# How can I automatically get the "Update Status" of a computer, as shown in the Settings?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I would like to get the `Update Status` automatically (the `Update Status` being the sentence `You're up to date` in the screenshot below).

[image]

I have found how to get the `Last checked` timestamp in PowerShell using:

```
$(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results.LastSearchSuccessDate;
```

However, trying to find the `Update Status` is completely eluding me. I'm not sure if the status itself is stored somewhere, or if the settings app determines the status based on the number of available updates, but I have not find a solution for replicating the status.

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve? I am not looking to automatically force the updates to install, I solely need to get the status.

The status is usually `You're up to date` or `Updates available`, but I do believe there are other statuses like `Update Failed`.

[image]

**Edit:** The following code does not seem to do what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: For the most part and for a great many users, Windows 10 just updates. There is a description in this article that details some of the problems that might occur for a few users:  https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-status-pending-install-download

Comment: @John "Windows 10 just updates" doesn't apply to my situation. I need a way to automate the process of checking the status for multiple computers. We are not looking for a way to change how automatic the actual update process is, just the checking of the status.

Comment: Why look for that string? It is not stored anywhere to be retrieved. It's delivered by the OS, in the OS logic. It's dynamically generated. Why are you note checking for both values, ***`$(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).Results`***. You can execute a detect, which is what Windows does when you use settings and compare date/state from that, as needed.

Comment: Even though you answered it already yourself, I would also take a look at the `PSWindowsUpdate` Module. It's super awesome, I used it to automate the complete update of all machines in my network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Microsoft.Update.Session` object to search the Assigned, Software updates that are not Hidden or already Installed. If none are found, there are no updates, otherwise there are some available:

```
$updateInfoMsg = "Windows Update Status: `n";

$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session;
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher();
$Updates = @($UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'").Updates);
$Found = ($Updates | Select-Object -Expand Title);

If ($Found -eq $Null) {
    $updateInfoMsg += "Up to date";
} Else {
    $Found = ($Updates | Select-Object -Expand Title) -Join "`n";
    $updateInfoMsg += "Updates available:`n";
    $updateInfoMsg += $Found;
}

$updateInfoMsg;
```

In order to run this on a remote computer, use `Invoke-Command`:

```
$server = "server";

<# Get Windows Update Info #>
$out += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

    $updateInfoMsg = "Windows Update Status: `n";
    
    $UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session;
    $UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher();
    $Updates = @($UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'").Updates);
    $Found = ($Updates | Select-Object -Expand Title);
    
    If ($Found -eq $Null) {
        $updateInfoMsg += "Up to date";
    } Else {
        $Found = ($Updates | Select-Object -Expand Title) -Join "`n";
        $updateInfoMsg += "Updates available:`n";
        $updateInfoMsg += $Found;
    }

    Return $updateInfoMsg;
}
$out;
```

Additionally, if you need to run this on a remote server that is not on the same domain, [follow my answer here to set it as a trusted host](https://superuser.com/a/1619309/1025486)

Here is an example output of the script:

```
    computer1
    ----------
    Windows Update Status: 
    Last Checked: 01/26/2021 13:40:39
    Up to date
    
    computer2
    ----------
    Windows Update Status: 
    Last Checked: 01/26/2021 05:59:41
    Updates available:
    2020-10 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 2004 for x64 (KB4578968)
    Feature update to Windows 10, version 20H2
```

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT Thanks! Haha, I was wondering if you were still following me along the ride for this specific script..,

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment. Whenever you fire off Settings and click Update. windows dynamically check for updates. You can do this yourself.

```
($WindowsUpdateInfo = $(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate)) | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{4a2f5c31-cfd9-410e-b7fb-29a653973a0f}

Name               MemberType   Definition                                  
----               ----------   ----------                                  
DetectNow          Method       void DetectNow ()                           
EnableService      Method       void EnableService ()                       
Pause              Method       void Pause ()                               
Resume             Method       void Resume ()                              
ShowSettingsDialog Method       void ShowSettingsDialog ()                  
Results            Property     IAutomaticUpdatesResults Results () {get}   
ServiceEnabled     Property     bool ServiceEnabled () {get}                
Settings           Property     IAutomaticUpdatesSettings Settings () {get} 
MSDN               ScriptMethod System.Object MSDN(); 
#>
```

Based on the results of the detection, you can use logic to spit out whatever message you choose.

```
If ($WindowsUpdateInfo.DetectNow() -eq $Null)
{"You're up to date"}
Else 
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Updates available
    Last checked: $($WindowsUpdateInfo.Results)"
}
```

See also for a similar take:

> https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-10-trigger-detecting-updates-from-command-line

Comment: At first this seemed to be working, but once I found a computer that had "Updates available" I ran this code and the logic of `DetectNow() -eq $Null` meaning that there aren't any updates waiting doesn't seem to work. I added a screenshot to my original post.